# Elasticsearch and Spanish Accents

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use elasticsearch to index some data about research paper. But I'am figthing to accents. For intance, if I use:

`GET /_analyze?tokenizer=standard&filter=asciifolding&text="Boletínes de investigaciónes"` I get

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "Bolet",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "nes",
         "start_offset": 7,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "de",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 13,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "investigaci",
         "start_offset": 14,
         "end_offset": 25,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "nes",
         "start_offset": 26,
         "end_offset": 29,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 5
      }
   ]
}
```

and I should to get something like that

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "Boletines",
         "start_offset": 1,
         "end_offset": 6,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "de",
         "start_offset": 11,
         "end_offset": 13,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "investigacion",
         "start_offset": 14,
         "end_offset": 25,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: I tried posting the uri in browser and  i am getting the expected output. http://localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=standard&filter=asciifolding&text=%22Bolet%C3%ADnes%20de%20investigaci%C3%B3nes%22

Comment: Yeah, In another machines work as expected but, not in my machine!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the extra tokens being formed, you need to use an alternative tokenizer, e.g. try the [whitespace tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html).

Alternatively use a [language analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html) and specify the language.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ASCII folding filter in your analyzer.

> For example, the filter changes à to a.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html